# Implementing Halley method for solving non-linear equations

Tags: equation-solving, function-construction

I would like to construct an operator say for the Halley methods which take a function as input, a initial point and a number of iteration.

I have tried this

```
 hal[f_, init_Real, n_Integer?Positive] := Module[{g = f},
 halley[0] := init
  halley[n] := 
  halley[n] = 
  halley[n - 1] - (2 f[halley[n - 1]] f'[halley[n - 1]])/(
  2 N[f'[halley[n - 1]]]^2 - 
    N[f[halley[n - 1]]] N[f''[halley[n - 1]]])]
```

Obviously it doesn't work even if outside of the module the recursion works.

Comment: "outside of the module the recursion works" Are you sure?

Comment: Yes if I define $f[x\_]:=x^2$ and fix $halley[0]:= 1$ (its arbitrary) I can ask halley[n] for any integer $n >=1$

Comment: No, I don't think you can, unless it's actually `halley[n_] := halley[n] =`

Comment: Sorry of course outside of the module I must type  halley[n_] := 
  halley[n] = ... inside the module if I do that the rest of the formula becomes red

Comment: Yeah, it'll become red, but you can't fix it by simply taking away the `_`.This only make things worse. The following will work, compare it to your original sample and think about why it works: `hal[f_, init_, nn_Integer?Positive] := 
 Module[{g = f, halley}, halley[0] := init ; 
  halley[n_] := 
   halley[n] = 
    halley[n - 1] - (2 f[halley[n - 1]] f'[halley[n - 1]])/(2 N[f'[halley[n - 1]]]^2 - 
        N[f[halley[n - 1]]] N[f''[halley[n - 1]]]); halley[nn]]`

Comment: I was thinking your porposal was not working  --- it is the case with $x^2$. But with pure functions --- #^2& --- it works. How to make it works with standard defined functions ---it's difficult to propose pure function inside that type of code.

Comment: A single `x^2` won't work, of course, you need to define it as a function: [Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/buGTs.png)

Comment: Of course I was obsessed to pass f[x] not f. Could it be both to prevent mistakes

Comment: A function like that can be defined, but it's totally a new problem, you'd better start a new question.

Comment: Ok I will ask a nexw question in all cases thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two points.

1. Use the built-in function `Nest` to do your recursion. Or, perhaps, `NestList` if you are more interested in the entire sequence generated by the iteration.
2. It is better for performance to pre-compute the derivative forms once and pass them into the function generator.

The generator is simply expressed by

```
halley[f_, df_, ddf_, init_?NumericQ] := 
  Nest[(# - (2. f[#] df[#])/(2. df[#]^2 - f[#] ddf[#]) &), init, #] &
```

For your example function

```
f[x_] := x^2
Block[{x}, df[x_] = f'[x]; dff[x_] = f''[x]];
```

the sequence generator is given by

```
halleyf[n_] := halley[f, df, dff, 1][n]
```

and then

```
Table[halleyf[n], {n, 7}]
```

> `{0.333333, 0.111111, 0.037037, 0.0123457, 0.00411523, 0.00137174, 0.000457247}`

which is the same sequence as given by

```
Table[N[1/3^n], {n, 7}]
```

Is this the sequence you expect?

It should work for any twice differentiable function. Let's try it with `Sin`.

```
halleySin[n_] := halley[Sin, Cos, -Sin[#] &, π/2 - 1/100][n]
Table[halleySin[n], {n, 5}]
```

> `{1.5408, 1.4809, 1.30349, 0.827218, 0.143852}`

#### Update

I see from a newer question that you want to use this method to solve non-linear equations. In that case, things can be made simpler by using `FixedPoint`.

```
 halleySolve[f_, df_, ddf_, init_?NumericQ] := 
   FixedPoint[(# - (2. f[#] df[#])/(2. df[#]^2 - f[#] ddf[#]) &), init]
```

Lets use this to find the square root of 42.

```
f[x_] := x^2 - 42
Block[{x}, df[x_] = f'[x]; dff[x_] = f''[x]];
root = halleySolve[f, df, dff, 21]
```

> `6.48074`

Verification

```
root^2
```

> `42.`

Let's also try Kepler's equation, a well-known non-linear equation of much use in orbit calculations.

```
kepler[t_] = t - Sin[t] - 7;
Block[{t}, dkepler[t_] = kepler'[t]; ddkepler[t_] = kepler''[t]];
halleySolve[kepler, dkepler, ddkepler, 2]
```

> `7.99067`

Verification

```
FindRoot[t - Sin[t] == 7, {t, 2}]
```

> `7.99067`

Comment: Since 3 month I try to master MA. Always I say to myself think functional programming and I forgot Nest. But in fact your method has some automatic differentiation reminiscence --- many people thinks wrogly that AD is the same that analytic but it's largely untrue --- because you define and transport the function and its two first order derivatives. It is especially clever because you can define a method and choose which ever definition of the derivative you want --- multiplicative, geometric etc. Brillant M. Goldberg.